# To solve the given cauchy Problem

Tags: partial-differential-equations

Solve the Cauchy Problem for $2z_x+yz_y=z$ for the initial data curve $C: x_0=S, y_0=s^2,z_0=1 , 1\le s\le 2$

Clearly, the Lagrange's auxillary equation is given as

$\frac{dx}{2}= \frac{dy}{y}=\frac{dz}{z}$

I choose the multiplier $P'=1, Q'=\frac{-1}{y}, R'=\frac{-1}{z}$
so that $PP'+QQ'+RR'=0$ where $P=2, Q=y, R=z$

On solving I got first solution to be $\frac{e^x}{yz}=c_1$ (check if I am wrong here)

Then I found other solution taking last two fractions 
as  $\frac{y}{z}=c_2$.

Then when I tried to find a relation between

$c_1 , c_2$ , it is obtained as $c_1c_2-e^(\frac{y}{z})^{1/2}$. (Am I right here?)

Then I am through. 
I just want to verify my answer . Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I don't get those relations for the characteristics (maybe you missed a plus sign in $\dfrac{e^{x/2}}{y+z}=c_1$, that is correct, although I prefer other form)

Integrating the first proportion, $\mathrm dx/2=\mathrm dy/y$,

$$\frac x2=\ln\vert y\vert +C_1\;;c_1=e^{-x}y^2$$

The second is right: $z/y=c_2$

You need to relate the two constants and $c_2=f(c_1)$, with $f$ a single argument, regular enough function, is such a relation. The general solution is:

$$\frac zy=f(e^{-x}y^2)$$

$$z(x,y)=yf(e^{-x}y^2)$$

Now we have to impose the boundary conditions (I hope not misunderstood them considering $S$ as constant):

$$1=s^2f(e^{-S}s^4)\;;\frac 1{s^2}=f(e^{-S}s^4)$$

We set $u={e^{-S}s^4}$ and isolating: $s=\sqrt[4]{e^{S}u}$

$$f(u)=\frac {1}{\sqrt{e^{S}u}}$$

Substituting:

$$z(x,y)=y\frac{1}{(e^Se^{-x}y^2)^{1/2}}=e^{(x-S)/2}$$